# What's the difference between end() and close() in io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketImplBase?

Tags: websocket, vert.x

These two methods are looked the same.
If both of them would close connections, the end() method seems to be obscure and redundant.

Are there any differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

The `end` method is inherited from `WriteStream`. By default it calls `close`.

If you don't use the websocket as a stream, simply call `close` in your code.

More on [streams](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#streams) in the Vert.x core documentation.